# Find unique answers from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have 2 lists:

```
texts = ["this is string 1", "this is string 2", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
```

I need to create a function that returns as many possible answers from `answers` (and their corresponding text) that exist in (exact string match) exactly one of the **returned texts**. That is, each of the returned answers must be in exactly one of the returned texts.

It should return a list of lists, where each sublist has the `[answer, corresponding text]`.

For example, in this example, only `"string 1"` appear in the first text (`"this is string 1"`), only `"string 3"` appear in the last text (`"this is string 3"`), and the first answer (`"this"`) appear in all of the texts, so it shouldn't be returned.

Another example:

```
texts = ["this is string 1 this is string 2", "this is string 1", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
```

The returned output in this case can either be

`[["string 1", "this is string 1"],["string 3", "this is string 3"]]`

Or

`[["string 1", "this is string 1 this is string 2"],["string 3", "this is string 3"]]`

As "string 1" does not appear in the returned text "this is string 3".

I currently have the following code:

```
def find_unique_answers(texts, answers):
    result = []
    for answer in answers:
        text_found = None
        for text in texts:
            if answer in text:
                if text_found is None:
                    text_found = text
                else:
                    text_found = None
                    break
        if text_found is not None:
            result.append([answer, text_found])
    return result

texts = ["this is string 1", "this is string 2", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]

output = find_unique_answers(texts, answers)
print(output)  # Output: [['string 1', 'this is string 1'], ['string 3', 'this is string 3']]
```

But, if I change the lists to

```
texts = ["this is string 1 this is string 2", "this is string 1", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
```

But the output is `[['string 3', 'this is string 3']]`

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: But `this is string 1` appears in the first 2 elements of `texts`.  And the only element of `texts` containing `this is string 3` is `this is string 3`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Right, but the output can still be `[["string 1","this is string 1"],["string 3", "this is string 3"]]`, as "string 1" does not appear in "this is string 3". Let me know if that clarified things, I know it's a bit confusing but I appreciate the help!

Comment: The description is still confusing. Could you maybe double-check the examples and provide a clear set of inputs/expected outputs?

Comment: I feel the result should be *"this is string 2"* as `"this"` and `"string 1"` both appear in `["this is string 1"` and `"this"` and "string 3" both appear in `"this is string 3"`

Comment: @BoppreH Tried to clarify! Let me know if this is better or if you have any more questions

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (I've added a new section to my answer), but now I get the same result as you. Are you sure the example texts are correct? Can you explain in your question, answer-by-answer and text-by-text, why the output should be different from `[['string 3', 'this is string 3']]`?

Comment: Sure! Just wondering, but does this not clarify your question? I'll try a different explanation if it doesn't. For my second example,  the returned output can either be
`[["string 1", "this is string 1"],["string 3", "this is string 3"]]` Or `[["string 1", "this is string 1 this is string 2"],["string 3", "this is string 3"]]`. As "string 1" does not appear in the returned text "this is string 3". So it's not about `string 1` not appearing in any of the original texts, but it just needs to not be in more than one of the returned ones

Comment: Ah, I see the different now. Is `[["this", "this is string 1"]]` and `[]` (no pairs) also valid answers?

Comment: @BoppreH Technically yes! But, both will be a smaller subset of returned items and I'm interested in as many possible answers.

Comment: @BoppreH If it simplifies things, for my use case I don't need more than 2 returned sublists, and the number of texts and answers is fairly small (<10)

Comment: Ah, I see now that "returned ones" was the key word. My bad, the problem makes complete sense. It's also a lot harder than I thought! I've edited my answer with a greedy algorithm.

Comment: @BoppreH Haha yea, it's a lot harder than I expected as well. Going to respond to your answer under it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: with the new explanations, I think I know understand the requirements better. It's an optimization problem, which is quite harder.

---

This is a brute-force approach that tries all combinations of answers. It's not completely stupid, but still takes exponential time. Given your comment on number of answers and texts it should be ok, though.

It always returns the largest amount of answers possible.

```
def find_all_answer_combinations(texts, answers, used_texts=()):
    if not texts or not answers:
        # Nothing to do, return an empty combination.
        yield ()
        return
    
    # Pick an answer to process.
    answer, *rest_answers = answers
    # Find solutions that *don't* use the selected answer.
    yield from find_all_answer_combinations(texts, rest_answers, used_texts)

    if any(answer in text for text in used_texts):
        # The answer already appears in a returned text, so we can't use it again.
        return

    # Find texts that have this answer.
    matched_texts = [text for text in texts if answer in text]
    # Only continue checking texts that don't contain the answer,
    # otherwise we'd have two or more matches for this answer.
    other_texts = [text for text in texts if answer not in text]
    # Try generating combinations with each of the matched texts.
    for matched_text in matched_texts:
        # Assuming we use `matched_text`, generate combinations
        # for the rest of answers/texts.
        for result in find_all_answer_combinations(other_texts, rest_answers, used_texts+(matched_text,)):
            yield (answer, matched_text), *result

def find_best_answers(texts, answers):
    # Finds the combination with most answers.
    return max(find_all_answer_combinations(texts, answers), key=len)

texts = ["this is string 1", "this is string 2", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
print(find_best_answers(texts, answers)) # (('string 1', 'this is string 1'), ('string 3', 'this is string 3'))

texts = ["this is string 1 this is string 2", "this is string 1", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
print(find_best_answers(texts, answers)) # (('string 1', 'this is string 1 this is string 2'), ('string 3', 'this is string 3'))

texts = ["this is string 1 this is string 2", "tis is string 1", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["tis", "string 1", "string 3"]
print(find_best_answers(texts, answers)) # (('string 1', 'this is string 1 this is string 2'), ('string 3', 'this is string 3'))
```

---

And this is a greedy algorithm that finds one combination of answers/texts pairs without conflicts. No guarantee on number of answers/texts returned:

```
def find_unique_answers(texts, answers):
    result = []
    forbidden_texts = []
    used_texts = []
    # Reversed order is a hack to get better results with the given examples.
    for answer in reversed(answers):
        # If the answer already matches a returned text, including
        # it here would result in two matching returned texts. So, we skip.
        if any(answer in text for text in used_texts): continue
        # Find all matching texts, ignoring the "forbidden ones"
        # that would conflict with used answers.
        matches = [text for text in texts if answer in text and text not in forbidden_texts]
        # No valid text, nothing to do. Skip.
        if not matches: continue
        # Arbitraryly select the first matching text.
        selected_text = matches[0]
        # We got ourselves a valid pair!
        result.append((answer, selected_text))
        # Remember the text we just used.
        used_texts.append(selected_text)
        # And add the other valid texts to "forbidden_texts",
        # so that future answers don't add extra matches to this one.
        forbidden_texts.extend(matches)
    return result

texts = ["this is string 1", "this is string 2", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
output = find_unique_answers(texts, answers)
print(output)  # Output: [('string 3', 'this is string 3'), ('string 1', 'this is string 1')]

texts = ["this is string 1 this is string 2", "this is string 1", "this is string 3"]
answers = ["this", "string 1", "string 3"]
output = find_unique_answers(texts, answers)
print(output) # [('string 3', 'this is string 3'), ('string 1', 'this is string 1 this is string 2')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Just to clarify, this code will by default aim for 2 answers/texts (if they exist)? Didn't quite understand it from your code/edit

Comment: @Penguin It always uses the first matching text, which what makes the algorithm "greedy". The `reversed` part is a trick that makes it give better results for the examples you gave, but there's no guarantee on the number of answers used. But good news: I just finished writing the algorithm that tries every combination, check the answer.

Comment: Amazing! Though I think there's an issue: `(('tis', 'tis is string 1'), ('string 1', 'this is string 1 this is string 2'), ('string 3', 'this is string 3'))` -- note that `string 1` appear in the text of the first and second tuple
`

Comment: @Peguin Ah, I had this case in the greedy algorithm, but forgot in the new version. Added to the brute-forcing algorithm.

Comment: I think this works!! Can't think of any other examples to try and everything I did worked : ) Thank you so much!! And apologies that the initial description was confusing, it was tricky to describe